# How can I join a guild?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I want to join a guild to get more XP, but I don't know how.

Comment: No need to ask more than one question, I'll answer it here. You must be a certain level to do certain things. If it says you must be level 80, then keep leveling up until you get to level 80.

Comment: @ChaseC Please don't change the question like that.  He was asking how to join a guild, not how to get an invite.  The only way might be *through* an invite, but that's not what he asked.

Comment: TarTar, I've removed your secondary question, as it's not related to your first one.  It doesn't look like that's been asked yet, so there's no reason not to ask that separately.

Comment: @Frank Understood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some general tips from [this forum](http://www.wowhead.com/forums&topic=28195/beginner-advice-for-joining-a-guild)

Ask around when you're online, in the cities. If someone just throws you an invite, decline it - most decent guilds ask before sending you an invite.

If I were you I'd ask something along the lines of "Looking for levelling guild, /w me info about guild before inviting".

If they don't tell you much, ask them things like when (and how many) players are usually online, do they provide advice to newbies, do they do regular events/dungeon runs. 
Good guild leaders give the kind of responses you want to hear.

If you don't have much luck in game, you could try posting in your official realm forum. I got a guild invite this way.

If you do end up joining a guild, and it's not what you hoped for - /gquit. I've been in a couple of dead guilds, where the members never chat, and one that just got too full of useless players.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you could simply go into a capital city and ask in Trade chat you are looking for a guild. Soon you will be flooded with invitations.

There is also a "*Looking for Guild*" screen which filters guilds based on some criteria (raids, pvp, availability, etc.) and you could send a request to join. Some member can review the requests and then send an invite. This is probably the slowest method of joining.

You can also go onto the Battle.net forums (I have not used this method, but it's worth mentioning).

### Review

1. Ask for guild in Trade chat
2. Use in-game guild finder
3. Use forums for recruitment

### Sources

1. Personal Experience
2. http://www.wowwiki.com/Guild_Finder
3. http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/1011639/